# Click Button Pressing Spacebar in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, button

I had 2 goals:

- Make pressing enter over a textbox start a search function
- Make pressing spacebar over a button perform a click(thought it was its behaviour, seems not)

I reached the first goal programmatically clicking the button of the seach, executing then the search function:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSearch.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        btnSearch.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

It worked, so I tried the same method with my second goal:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles btnCancel.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Then
        btnCancel.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

And this actually does nothing, kinda select the button, but it doesn't process the button_click event.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim btn As New MouseButtons   'create a new instance of mousebutton
Dim a As New MouseEventArgs(btn, 1, 1, 1, 1) 'simulate a click

If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Then
  Button1_MouseClick(sender, a)
End If
```

Comment: Cannot convert KeyEventArgs into MouseEventArgs due I'm using MouseClick and not Click, Any solution w/o using Click?

Comment: Is it correct or do I incur in some errors using btnCancel_MouseClick(Nothing, Nothing)? It seems working properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to Call BtnCancel.Focus() Before Btncancel.Keydown() or  Btncancel.KeyPress() event